# Is it possible to output with specific index?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I want to get specific variable of amount.

Is it possible to say something, like: if index == 1 then return first amount? where possible amounts are: "3333" "444" "555"
If it is possible, how can I do it in the code?

query:

```
items{
    name
    amount
  }
```

```
const { data } = useQuery(ITEMS)

{data.items.map((items, index) => ( <p>{items.amount}</p>))}
```

Comment: Isn't `data.items` just a regular 'ol array?

Comment: @Alexander it is part of query. I ve edited the post

Comment: Are you only wanting to only RECIEVE the data for an index, or just only DISPLAY the data of a specific index (where you can recieve all the data, but only display the specific index)?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I want to display the data, with specific index

Comment: @Ontolf Like, give the user a slider where they can pick the index or a number input, or a constant number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, do this, and you can replace the `1` with whatever index you want (remember, indexing starts at 0, so this `1` means the second value. if you want the first, replace it with 0).

```
<p>{data.items[1].amount}</p>
```